# CMake: How to build multiple libraries within the CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

Using LLVM, I try to create multiple modules within a single project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

project("SplitWMPass")

add_library(SplitWMPass MODULE
    # List your source files here.
        SplitWMPass.cpp
)

add_library(WMCheckerTPass MODULE
        WMCheckerTPass.cpp)


# LLVM is (typically) built with no C++ RTTI. We need to match that;
# otherwise, we'll get linker errors about missing RTTI data.
set_target_properties(SplitWMPass PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-fno-rtti"
)

# Get proper shared-library behavior (where symbols are not necessarily
# resolved when the shared library is linked) on OS X.
if(APPLE)
    set_target_properties(SplitWMPass PROPERTIES
        LINK_FLAGS "-undefined dynamic_lookup"
    )
endif(APPLE)
```

This works just fine, if I only specify one `add_library()`, but using two of them makes the second library fail:

```
nlykkei@nlykkei-Ubuntu:~/llvm-ir-obfuscation$ opt -load cmake-build-debug/water/libWMCheckerTPass.so 
Error opening 'cmake-build-debug/water/libWMCheckerTPass.so': cmake-build-debug/water/libWMCheckerTPass.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN4llvm10ModulePassE
```

I would like to know how to build multiple libraries within the project?

Everything works just fine, if I build the second library in an entirely new folder with its own CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: It is possible to specify several libraries in the same CMakeLists.txt. Can you show the CMakeLists.txt that is not working?

Comment: The one that Ive shown

Comment: Maybe your second library needs the same target properties, especially the `-undefined dynamic_lookup` part. If yes, you just need to copy the `set_target_properties` line for the second library.

Comment: Does adding `target_link_libraries(WMCheckerTPass  SplitWMPass)` solve your problem? That would link the second library to the first possibly solving the undefined symbol.

Comment: @Antonio - I will try it out thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this in your `CMakeLists.txt`

`set_target_properties(WMCheckerTPass PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-fno-rtti"
)`

Your `LLVM` toolchain was built with RTTI disabled (the default), but your new module has that enabled, so you need to copy `LLVM` build settings since your library will be loaded by `opt` and you shouldn't generate symbols that are currently not there (as is the case with your error).

Alternatively, if you run this on your terminal:

`c++filt _ZTIN4llvm10ModulePassE`

you will get

`typeinfo for llvm::ModulePass`

which is a clear indication.

It's a good idea to also copy `LLVM`'s settings for exceptions.
See a basic example CMake file [here](https://github.com/compor/llvm-skeletons/blob/master/skeleton-opt-minimal-pass/CMakeLists.txt). The key file to look at in your `LLVM` installation in conjunction with CMake is `LLVMConfig.cmake`.

The relevant documentation can be found [here](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#embedding-llvm-in-your-project).

Comment: Thank you - what do you mean by "I shouldn't generate symbols that are currently not there"? Why does RTTI on one module break things if linked with a program where it is disabled?

Comment: having RTTI generates runtime info symbols, because they are used in your module, but they are not defined there because they are part of the `LLVM` API which gets compiled and linked against `opt`, which loads your module and dynamically resolves any missing "pieces". In the above case, those pieces are not there, because when opt was compiled, it was with RTTI disabled.